# Check for missing (nonexistent / tampered) query string and redirect to a 400 BAD REQUEST page (WebMatrix / Razor syntax)

Tags: query-string, webmatrix, bad-request, tampering

I can test query strings parameters:

```
Request.QueryString["value"].IsEmpty()
Request.QueryString["value"].Isint()
Etc.
```

But how can I **avoid** that there is **no query string at all** ?
In other words, I want to `prevent` users to access `the root` of each folder or subfolder.

```
    http://localhost:16838/auth/provider.cshtml

instead of:

    http://localhost:16838/auth/provider.cshtml?providerId=7
```

If I remove the query string (up to the page extension), I get a `cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`error since the next part of the code is still executed.

Instead, I would like the user be `redirect` to a `400 BAD REQUEST`:

```
The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.
The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users can't "access the root of the folder" by omitting a querystring value. All that will happen if they request `http://localhost:16838/auth/provider.cshtml` instead of `http://localhost:16838/auth/provider.cshtml?providerId=7` is that any code that relies on `Request["providerId"]` having a value will likely blow up.

If you want to test if a query string value exists, you only need to use IsEmpty():

```
if(Request["providerId"].IsEmpty()){
    //the value is missing. Redirect ot a safe page or provide a default value
} else {
    //run your code
}
```

Comment: Found my error. In HTML section, missing variable to prevent unexistent data display -> if(Request["providerId"].IsEmpty()){tampering = true + ModelState.AddFormError(bla bla} / in HTML if (tampering) {@Html.ValidationSummary()) else {display data}

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make sure there is no query sting value at all you could check `Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx

But, most likely you want to be checking individual values and you should be able to do this:

```
if(Request.QueryString["key"] == null || Request.QueryString["key"].IsEmpty()) 
{
  // redirect
}
```

Comment: In fact, it is the contrary (sorry, I reformulated my question that was, I must admit, ambigous): I want to be sure that there is ALWAYS a query string and PREVENT users to access root folders or subfolders by removing the query strings from the URL. A the moment, if they do it, they get a "cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" error. I tested already if(Request.QueryString["key"] != null but it didn't help. I think it is because the string is not even null but simply doesn't exist (no ?). I saw something in ASP.Net (isNothing) but couldn't find an equivalent for WebMatrix razor.

Comment: .IsEmpty() has an error. What library should I import?